# How to fix Python error "...failed to map segment from shared object" appearing when I try to import NumPy library on GCP?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shell, numpy, google-cloud-platform

I've recently started to use Google Cloud Platform and I run my python scripts in Cloud Shell within Linux environment.

By running one of the scripts  that is using pandas library I ran into very unpleasant error which is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas_excercises.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/dann_frol/.local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
was
installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:
  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.0"
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
Original error was: /home/dann_frol/.local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I've checked both  python and numpy versions and they seem to match to the ones described in the error message.
I've tried to reinstall both pandas and numpy using `python3 -m pip uninstall pandas` and `python3 -m pip install pandas` , however it didn't help.

When I run the code, I use the following command: python3 pandas_excercises.py

Some info about the OS:

```
  Operating System: Container-Optimized OS from Google
            Kernel: Linux 4.19.114+
      Architecture: x86-64
```

What could be the possible issue and how to fix this error?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly are you running the scripts? [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/concepts)? A [Compute Engine VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute)?

Comment: Hi @DanielOcando, I am running my code in Cloud Shell.

Comment: @ViniLL How did you install Numpy?

Comment: @a_guest using "python3 -m pip install pandas"

Comment: Cloud Shell is a virtual appliance that uses Debian Linux. GKE cluster nodes or standalone GCE VM instances running container images use Container-Optimized OS (COS). The provided "Some info about the OS:  `Operating System: Container-Optimized OS from Google`" does not match Cloud Shell. It's still not clear where are you launching your Python script. Could you please double-check where the Python code is launched (in Cloud Shell or on a Compute Engine instance) and let us know the OS version?

Comment: @mebius99 I am  running my code in Cloud Shell terminal , and I am using it to connect to my Compute Engine instance. Sorry for the confusion, since I am new to it and might not understand all the details. The provided info about OS was obtained by typing `hostnamectl` command  in the terminal. I am getting same OS version if I use `uname -a` command , which outputs `Linux webhook-bot 4.19.114+ #1 SMP Sat Apr 11 01:31:21 PDT 2020 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux` . Is there any other command I should use to get the OS version?

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: @mebius99 it returns the following : 

`NAME="Container-Optimized OS"
ID=cos
PRETTY_NAME="Container-Optimized OS from Google"
HOME_URL="https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/support-policy#contact_us"
KERNEL_COMMIT_ID=a8c47ac5afe9c1a9f569b2caaa93b803a6c4d94b
GOOGLE_METRICS_PRODUCT_ID=26
GOOGLE_CRASH_ID=Lakitu
VERSION=83

VERSION_ID=83

BUILD_ID=13020.12.0`

Comment: @ViniLL Did you find any solution to the issue

Answer (score 14):

I'm pretty sure that in case of Python libraries' natives, the message `failed to map segment from shared object` means that the `.so` file isn't marked executable. (`ls -l` says e.g. `-rw-r--r--` instead of `-rwxr-xr-x`.)

The only way (that I can think of) how it can be so after a sane `pip install` is if filesystem is mounted with `noexec` flag. (Which was the case on my setup.) You can quickly check for it using `mount` command, it will be listed among other flags inside braces if it is set.

How to remove that `noexec` flag is another question.

Comment: Yeah, python building from /tmp and needing to link into a shared lib with exec trips over security best practice to not mount /tmp with exec permissions. Quick temp fix is `sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp`, or else make the change permanent in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, but pls how exactly can I make the change pernament? What should I write to /etc/fstab?

Comment: Another quick resolution is to execute `TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp pip install -r requirements.txt`. This leaves the tmp filesystem as noexec but makes pip use the filesystem of $HOME for its intermediate build steps.

Comment: Yup, I had /tmp as noexec... I guess I deserve to be punished for following basic security practices.

Answer (score 2):

Container-Optimized OS (COS) has several limitations that could be a reason that your program does not work.

COS is an operating system optimized for running Docker containers. But it lacks many of components you have in a typical Linux distribution. This distribution components and especially a kernel are quite different from the generic Linux installation.

[Container-Optimized OS Overview => Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#limitations):

> Container-Optimized OS has limited or no support for some of the common features you may be familiar with on other operating systems:
>
> - Container-Optimized OS does not include a package manager; as such, you'll be unable to install software packages directly on an instance.
> - Container-Optimized OS **does not support execution of non-containerized applications**.
> - The Container-Optimized OS kernel is locked down; you'll be unable to install third-party kernel modules or drivers.

[Container-Optimized OS > OS Security > Immutable root filesystem and verified boot](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#immutable_root_filesystem_and_verified_boot):

> The Container-Optimized OS **root filesystem is always mounted as read-only**. Additionally, its checksum is computed at build time and verified by the kernel on each boot. Additionally, several other mounts are non-executable by default. See [Filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#filesystem) for details.

Additional information: [Container-Optimized OS Overview](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits)

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info. Would you know the possible workaround or the solution for my issue? The OS allows me to install it this library, however it is something wrong when I am trying to import it